# How to check if 2 qubits are entangled?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

I know that 2 qubits are entangled if it is impossible to represent their joint state as a tensor product. But when we are given a joint state, how can we tell if it is possible to represent it as a tensor product?
For example, I am asked to tell if the qubits are entangled for each of the following situations:

$$\begin{align}
\left| 01 \right>\\
\frac 12(\left| 00  \right> + i\left| 01  \right> - i\left| 10  \right> +  i\left| 11  \right> )\\
\frac 12(\left| 00 \right> - \left| 11  \right>)\\
\frac 12(\left| 00  \right> + \left| 01  \right> +i\left| 10  \right> +  \left| 11  \right> )  \end{align}$$

Comment: Are you given all the coefficients of $\mid 01 \rangle$ etc? Or are you thinking more as given 2 physical qubits and you can only perform unitaries and measurements?

Comment: For example, I am asked to tell if the qubits are entangled for each of the following situations:| 01>   1/2*(|00> + i*|01> +i*|10> +  i*|01> )        1/2*(|00> - |11>)

Comment: I will edit my question, thereI will use math notations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are given a general 2-qubit state $a \mid 00 \rangle + b \mid 01 \rangle + c \mid 10 \rangle + d \mid 11 \rangle$

If it is unentangled, then the coefficients are that of $(\alpha \mid 0 \rangle + \beta \mid 1 \rangle)(\gamma\mid 0 \rangle + \delta \mid 1 \rangle)$ for some $\alpha .. \delta$.

$$
\alpha \gamma = a\\
\alpha \delta = b\\
\beta \gamma = c\\
\beta \delta = d
$$

You want to know if those 4 equations are solvable for a given $a,b,c,d$. This question becomes

$$
ad - bc = 0
$$

so if $ad-bc=0$, then you can solve for $\alpha .. \delta$. You don't need to solve for them, you just need to need to know if it is possible.

The generalization for qudits with potentially different values of $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the quadratic polynomials that cut out the [Segre embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) as a zero locus.

Comment: Could you please show me how you would solve the third problem from my example? (1/2* (|00> - |11>))

Comment: You forgot to normalize, but it doesn't matter for this problem. $a=1/2$, $b=c=0$, $d=-1/2$. $ad-bc=-1/4 \neq 0$ so entangled.

Answer (score 3):

It is done for a specific state (a Bell state) [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/how-do-i-show-that-a-two-qubit-state-is-an-entangled-state), and the same procedure can be used for any other two-qubit state.