# How to know if any two arbitrary qubits are entangled?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, measurement

Suppose there are two quits called `q1` and `q2`. They are in two different superposition states. If we represent their states on the Bloch sphere surface, `q1` is located at `point_1` and `q2` is placed at `point_2`. Please note that `point_1` is different from `point_2` and we know where `point1` and `point2` are. Now, my question consists of two parts:

1. How to make `q1` and `q2` entangled?
2. After making them entangled, how to check if they are entangled indeed?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/how-do-i-show-that-a-two-qubit-state-is-an-entangled-state